# refering the specific div after click another div using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am looking in jquery to

- Make a div containing an icon make awesome and a text clickable => div List 1
- when clicking this div, I am redirected to another div containing an element table with a text Return list 1
- when clicking on Back list 1, I am back to the top ie on the div List 1

[image]

Comment: Hey so your asking how to do, what your looking into ?

Comment: Could you please specify step by step output state on input ...

Answer (score 1):

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

```js
 $("#list1").click(function(){
  //this will show list 1
  
     $( "#list2cont" ).hide( "fast")
    $( "#list1cont" ).show( "slow")
    

  
}); 

 $("#list2").click(function(){
  //this will show list 1
  
     $( "#list1cont" ).hide( "fast")
    $( "#list2cont" ).show( "slow")
    

  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="list1">list 1</div>
<div id="list2">list 2</div>


<div hidden id="list1cont"> list 1 content</div>
<div hidden id="list2cont"> list 2 contnet</div>
```

Hey hope your well this is the most basic answer to what it is you were asking for hope this helps, i left out the styling and belive that you can do